# How do I create a class diagram for a NetLogo program?

Tags: netlogo

I have a bunch of globals, lots of procedures but I don't know how I'm supposed to represent inheritance or interfaces and relationships. Anyone have a basic idea on how to build one where to start?

Answer (score 2):

The NetLogo language is procedurally based, not class based, and has no real concept of inheritance.  Nevertheless, you could diagrammatically represent turtles as a class with attributes (`turtles-own`) and methods (procedures than run in turtle context).  You could also similarly represent any breed as "inheriting" from `Turtle`.